# C# PictureBox Won't Display

Tags: c#, hidden, picturebox

I placed a `PictureBox` inside a `GroupBox` and it was working fine but now, nothing. I tried moving it to the front of the form, the Visible property is set to true, and set it's border to `FixedSingle` just in case it was an issue with the image file but nothing displays. This seems very strange. Any ideas what it could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding some other control to the groupbox like a button or label. 

This will tell you if it is the groupbox or picture box.

Then try adding the picturebox to a panel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `GroupBox` is visible, if it where invisible the controls inside it will be invisible too.

Also make sure that your `GroupBox` is in front of other controls in the form, and so to the `pictureBox`, it should be in front of other controls within the `groupBox` itself.

However if you are referring to the image inside the `pictureBox` that is not displayed, that is a different story then, you should make sure that you are assigning the `pictureBox.Image` or `pictureBox.BackgroundImage`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Apparently, I somehow managed to mess up my form designer. Nothing I added (or changed) would display upon rebuilding. I fixed it and it works fine now, weird. Thanks anyway.